# How to make rotation use 3X3 matrix in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a 3X3 matrix, like this:

```
[ a11  a12  a13 ]
[ a21  a22  a23 ]
[ a31  a32  a33 ]
```

but how can I make rotation use this matrix to a mesh in THREE.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to specify a mesh's orientation via a matrix. To do so, you can use one of the following two patterns:

```
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4(); // create once and reuse it

matrix.set(
    a11, a12, a13,  0,
    a21, a22, a23,  0,
    a31, a32, a33,  0,
      0,   0,   0,  1
);
```

If you know the matrix is a rotation matrix (i.e., no scaling involved),

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

mesh.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix( matrix );
```

Otherwise,

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

mesh.applyMatrix( matrix );
```

three.js r.94

Comment: it works. thanks.  also i have a translation coordinate [x1, y1, z1], a 3X3 rotation matrix [ a11  a12  a13 ]
[ a21  a22  a23 ]
[ a31  a32  a33 ], a scale [x2, y2, z2], how to combine these into one 4X4 matrix

Comment: `mesh.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix( matrix ); mesh.scale.set( x2, y2, z2 ); mesh.position.set( x1, y1, z1 );` Welcome to SO. You can accept answers by clicking on the checkmark.