# THREE.js: how to make a 4X4 matrix for translate, rotation and scale

Tags: three.js

I have these:

a translation:

```
[x1, y1, z1]
```

a 3X3 rotation matrix:

```
[ a11  a12  a13 ]
[ a21  a22  a23 ]
[ a31  a32  a33 ]
```

a scale:

```
[x2, y2, z2]
```

how to combine these into one 4X4 matrix, which is used for mesh.applyMatrix().

thanks.

Comment: Good question and good answer, but just a comment. You could also avoid the construction of the matrix. See the comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583342/1100107

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notation, construct your transform matrix like so:

```
matrix.set(
    x2 * a11, y2* a12, z2 * a13,  x1,
    x2 * a21, y2* a22, z2 * a23,  y1,
    x2 * a31, y2* a32, z2 * a33,  z1,
           0,       0,        0,   1
);
```

three.js r.94